# Create two way swipe for two actions such as delete and reply in Custom Listview Android

Tags: android, listview, swipe-gesture

**I want to create like as shown in below picture.**
[This is sample Screenshot of two way swipe in listview that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoSOs.png)
Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) is exactly what you need.
Add it to your dependies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
}
```

and use as mentioned in the example.

Comment: @HardikMehta.Please accept the answer if it helped.